# Flex / Actionscript drag and drop / swipe effect (simulate android / ios interface)

Tags: android, ios, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to simulate the interface of mobile (ios / android)...

1. Drag the menu and you will see the part of previous or next page content
2. Release the menu and if you have dragged over 30% of page content. It will do the transition between current page and target page.

I am just wondering is there any library or Flex component have already provided the above features? I have google it but got nothing related to these features (wrong keyword?..).  I can code it by hand but I would like to check whether my approach is the best way to do so...

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you find anything, let us know! I too have looked for a lib that provides that functionality for a long time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Flex Mobile SDK, you'll note a similar interface, user experience, and functionality as found within native iOS applications.

The List component appears similar to iOS, such as how the scroll bar renders and the ability to spring before the list.

I would take a look at Jason's Flex Blog from Adobe, Mobile List Paging with Page Indicator Skin:

http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2011/11/mobile-list-paging-with-page-indicator-skin.html

[image: Page Scrolling 1]
[image: Page Scrolling 2]

```
<s:List id="pagedList"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
        pageScrollingEnabled="true"
        itemRenderer="renderers.BackgroundColorRenderer"
        skinClass="skins.PagedListSkin">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout orientation="rows" requestedRowCount="1"
                      columnWidth="{pagedList.width}" rowHeight="{pagedList.height}"
                      verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="colorData">
        <fx:Number>0xFF0000</fx:Number>
        <fx:Number>0xFF9900</fx:Number>
        <fx:Number>0xFFFF00</fx:Number>
        <fx:Number>0x00FF00</fx:Number>
        <fx:Number>0x0000FF</fx:Number>
        <fx:Number>0x9900FF</fx:Number>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:List>
```

There is a FXP of the project there.

Comment: Those are all standard Flex components that (unfortunately) don't mimic the behavior described by @Rex. What is needed here is basically a method to get the current touchpoint and drag the current content based on that point. Basically the effect when you swipe between home screens on iOS. The default Flex swipe gesture, however, doesn't implement the current touch point, it just gives you an index which represents the direction you swiped to.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.flex-blog.com/using-swipe-gestures-in-mobile-flex-application-air-for-android/

Comment: If I may quote the article you posted: "When this property is -1, the swipe was to the left, when its 1, to swipe was to the right.". So exactly what I said, the swipe gesture gives you a simple index whether you swiped left or right, not the actual touchpoint which would be required for @Rex'ses required functionality. It's not about the transition between the containers, but how this transition is eventually triggered. You can't 'pull' the next container, it becomes visible to the extent you pulled and if you pull further the view switches. It just doesn't work out of the box with Flex.

Comment: Depending on the overall simulation desired, it may be more feasible to extend Flex Mobile rather than roll your own iOS / Android implementation using Tweeners.  Measure the component vs. focusing on the swipe gesture.  To each their own - I've found this type of functionality trivial using the SDK.

Comment: Many thanks for @Jason Sturges and @Al_Birdy replies :) Like what @ Al_Birdy said, I am looking for a way to implement a feature that pulling a next container and let part of next container become visible. I have just taken a look on the `TransformGestureEvent` and `ViewNavigator`. It doesn't meet the requirements indeed. My current approach is... using `MouseEvent` or `TouchEvent` to trigger dragging motion of large container which contains pages. When dragging has been stopped, find out the difference between start point and end point and start transition if necessary. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Rex - at a higher-level, you can check the scroll position of the container instead of focusing on the swipe action itself.  The List container as cited above will have rendered previous / next pages.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Sturges !! It is exactly what I wanted =]

Answer (score 0):

i think you'll need to code the 30%-logic/etc. in any case - but here are some links you'll find useful:

1. [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/) - super handy, very flexible, very simple and straightforward compared to the cool things you can do with it; especially useful when you want to quickly test a concept
2. a [chapter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f6a.html) in the book
3. [fl.transitions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/package-detail.html)